# Is $TS^n$ diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

For what values of $n \neq 1,3,7$ is the tangent bundle $TS^n$ of the $n$-sphere diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$?

Comment: It's definitely not true in the case $n=2$. The unit tangent sphere bundle in this case has total space $SO(3) \cong \Bbb RP^3$, and it is well-known that $\Bbb RP^3$ doesn't embed in $\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: @JohnKlein It's simpler than that; such a sphere in $\Bbb R^{2n}$ would have nontrivial self-intersection. It's not possible for any even $n$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Right!

Comment: @MikeMiller I guess this argument works with "homeomorphic"?

Comment: @YCor Right, though now you probably want to phrase intersection numbers / the rest of the argument in terms of compactly supported cohomology.

Comment: @JohnKlein Do you know a proof that $T^1 S^5$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S^4 \times S^5$? I'd like to try to use whatever invariant distinguishes these as an obstruction somehow.

Comment: @MikeMiller I don't have  complete argument, but here's an idea: the total space is of the form $(S^4 \vee S^5) \cup_f D^9$. The attaching map $f: S^8 \to S^4 \vee S^5$  has 3 components: $\pi_8(S^4) + \pi_8(S^5) + \pi_8(S^8)$ where the second component is trivial because the bundle has a section. It's enough to show that the first component is non-trivial after suspending once into $\pi_9(S^5) \cong \Bbb Z/2$. I suspect that the unstable $J$-homomorphism  $\pi_4(SO(5)) \to \pi_9(S^5)$ is an isomorphism.  
If true,  the result follows as the tangent bundle of $S^5$ is non-trivial.

Answer (score 3):

There are no sphere's with non-trivial normal bundle in that dimension. As far as I know, this is  originally a theorem of Massey. See http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1959-010-06/S0002-9939-1959-0109351-8/S0002-9939-1959-0109351-8.pdf for details.

Comment: Massey cites Kervaire in 1(c) for a slightly more general theorem in [this Annals paper](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kervhopf.pdf). Using Massey's approach, one does need to fill in the detail that the unit tangent bundle has nontrivial fiber homotopy type, which is probably known but you'd need to know something about the unstable J-homomorphism. Kervaire's approach seems more elementary.

Comment: @PVAL  Thank you  very  much  for  your  answer  and  very  interesting link of the  paper  of Massey.

Comment: @MikeMiller  according to the  paper  of  Massey provided  by PVAL I  understand it  is  impossible  for  n even, using  tubular neighborhood  theorem and  non vanishing  of  Euler  characteristic. But  can you ellaborate your  answer  for  $n$ odd. Are you using  Alexander duality?If yes, how  is  your  computation? what  is  the  role  of  "handles"?Thanks again for  your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Take $n$ odd; this is never possible for $n$ even. Suppose the unit disc bundle of $TS^{n}$ embeds in $S^{2n}$. One may calculate the relative homology of its complement (relative to the boundary) to be supported in degrees $n+1$ and $2n$, and so after appropriate handle cancellation can be obtained by attaching precisely one handle in each of those degrees. But where are we attaching the $(n+1)$-handle on $T^1 S^n$? Its attaching sphere homologous to a section of the bundle; I claim that any sphere in that homology class is isotopic to a section. This is at least true in a sufficiently [stable range](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2155036?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) $(n \geq 6)$ so that homotopy classes of $n$-spheres only contain a single isotopy type. But you can identify the normal bundle of the section with the subbundle of $TS^n$ your section splits off; if this is trivial, then your tangent bundle itself must have been trivial, so $n = 1, 3, 7$ (or I suppose $5$, because I don't know whether there are some extra isotopy classes I don't want for some reason).

Comment: I guess you could just as well verify that $T^1 S^n$ never arises as an $(n-2)$-surgery on $S^{2n-1}$, which should be elementary calculation once you know there aren't very many knots.

Comment: Thank  you  very  much  for  your  answer. I  try  to  understand the  detail.